# monacaでlandscape時のスプラッシュスクリーンの表示方法(android)

Tags: android, monaca, cordova

いつもお世話になっております。
monacaを利用して、cordovaハイブリッドアプリを開発しています。
スプラッシュスクリーンが表示されない問題が発生しています。
（指定した秒数の間は画面が暗転し、その後トップページが表示されます）

こちらで試した内容は以下の２点です。
いずれもスプラッシュスクリーンは表示されませんでした。

1.アプリを新規作成 
　アプリの設定 > [Android] > 画面の向き：[Landscape]として設定
　デバッグビルド

2.アプリを新規作成
  アプリの設定 > [Android] > 画面の向き：[Landscape]として設定
  横画面用の9.png画像を用意し、config.xmlを

```
<splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-land-mdpi.9.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
```

と変更し、デバッグビルド

２を試した際、ビルドログには

```
cp: no such file or directory: /private/tmp/monaca/*************/project/res/android/screen/splash-land-mdpi.9.png
```

と表示されてしまいます。

---

スプラッシュファイルの設定画面には画面の向きごとの設定もないので、一括でいけるものかと考えていたのですが、どうやら違うようです...
解決策をご存知の方、ご教授頂けますでしょうか？

プロジェクト構成と、config.xmlは以下のになります。

○プロジェクト構成
[HelloWorld]
　∟[.monaca]
　∟[platforms]
　∟[res]
　　∟[android]
　　　∟[icon]
　　　∟[screen]
　　　　　∟ splash-land-hdpi.png
　　　　　∟ splash-land-ldpi.png
　　　　　∟ splash-land-mdpi.png
　　　　　∟ splash-land-xhdpi.png
　　　　　∟ splash-land-xxhdpi.png
　　　　　∟ splash-land-xxxhdpi.png
　　　　　∟ splash-port-hdpi.png
　　　　　∟ splash-port-ldpi.png
　　　　　∟ splash-port-mdpi.png
　　　　　∟ splash-port-xhdpi.png
　　　　　∟ splash-port-xxhdpi.png
　　　　　∟ splash-port-xxxhdpi.png
　　∟[ios]
　　∟[winrt]
  ∟ .gitignore
  ∟ config.xml
  ∟ LICENSE
  ∟[www]
    ∟[components]
    ∟[css]
    ∟ index.html

○ config.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="com.example.helloworld" version="1.0.0">
  <name>Hello World App</name>
  <description>Made with Monaca (http://monaca.mobi)</description>
  <author/>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG"/>
  <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop"/>
  <preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud"/>
  <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="250"/>
  <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>
  <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false"/>
  <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray"/>
  <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0"/>
  <preference name="PageLength" value="0"/>
  <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page"/>
  <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated"/>
  <feature name="LocalStorage">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage"/>
  </feature>
  <preference name="UIWebViewDecelerationSpeed" value="normal"/>
  <preference name="ios-XCBuildConfiguration-TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY" value="1,2"/>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <icon src="/res/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x~ipad.png" width="167" height="167"/>
    <splash src="/res/ios/screen/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="/res/ios/screen/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="/res/ios/screen/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="/res/ios/screen/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="/res/ios/screen/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="/res/ios/screen/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    <splash src="/res/ios/screen/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="/res/ios/screen/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="/res/ios/screen/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="/res/ios/screen/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleLocalizations" target="*-Info.plist">
      <array>
        <string>en</string>
      </array>
    </config-file>
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="/res/android/icon/ldpi.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="/res/android/icon/mdpi.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="/res/android/icon/hdpi.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="/res/android/icon/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="/res/android/icon/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="/res/android/icon/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-port-xxhdpi.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-port-xxxhdpi.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-land-xxhdpi.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="/res/android/screen/splash-land-xxxhdpi.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="/res/winrt/icon/package_logo_winrt.png" target="StoreLogo"/>
    <icon src="/res/winrt/icon/app_logo_winrt.png" target="Square150x150Logo"/>
    <icon src="/res/winrt/icon/app_small_logo_winrt.png" target="Square30x30Logo"/>
    <icon src="/res/winrt/icon/app_tile_wide_logo_winrt.png" target="Wide315x150Logo"/>
    <splash src="/res/winrt/screen/app_splash_screen_winrt.png" width="620" height="300"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="chrome">
    <icon src="/platforms/chrome/icon.png" width="128" height="128"/>
  </platform>
  <preference name="WindowsStorePublisherName" value="My Name"/>
  <preference name="WindowsStoreIdentityName" value="ca30d585-5e70-ddeb-e273-f4ffe0bd1059"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
  <preference name="monaca:AndroidIsPackageNameSeparate" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000"/>
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: 2. の件については単純にpathの間違いではないでしょうか。該当プラグインのGitHubでの例示は`<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>`とされているので`screen`と`android`の順序が逆のように見えます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！確かにGitHubの例だと順序が逆のようですが、monacaで新規作成した場合、私の示したフォルダ構成になっているようです。

Comment: なるほどpath自体はあっているのですね。一つ質問なのですが、問題は「横画面のスプラッシュスクリーンが表示されない」であってますでしょうか？（縦画面にすればスプラッシュスクリーンは表示される＝プラグインが適用できていないわけではない）

Comment: はい、その通りです。縦画面(Portrait)ではスプラッシュスクリーンは表示されています。横画面のみ表示されない状態です。

Comment: 現状の情報だけだと原因の特定は厳しそうです。可能であればプロジェクトの構成や、config.xmlの全文など提示してもらえると推測できるかもしれません。

Comment: 遅くなってしまい、申し訳ありません。質問内容の方にプロジェクト構成とconfig.xmlを追加しました。

お手数ですが、確認をお願い致します。

Comment: (pathを間違えたのでコメント訂正しました)monacaの場合はsplash画像のコピーに何か処理入れているかもしれませんね。試せていませんがsrcに渡すpathを‌`​.monaca-res/res/android/scre‌​en/splash-la‌​nd-mdpi.png`のようにするとどう‌​なるでしょうか？

Comment: 試してみましたが、同様のエラーが出てしまいますね。
`cp: no such file or directory: /private/tmp/monaca/*************/project/​.monaca-res/res/android/screen/splash-land-ldpi.png`
もしかしてmonacaの不具合なのでしょうか？

Comment: 回答に詳細を書いてみました。不具合か仕様かはMonacaのサポートに問い合わせてみないとわかりませんね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monacaのサポートに問い合わせないとわからないかもしれません。

通常のCordovaのスプラッシュスクリーンであれば、

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<splash src="[src-path]" density="[density]">
```

のように指定した場合、ビルド時に以下のように画像がコピーされます。

```
`[src-path]` => <ビルド環境>/platform/android/res/drawable-[density]/<SplashScreen名>.png
```

発生しているエラーから推測すると、`[src-path]`に指定したパスが
`/private/tmp/monaca/*************/project/res/android/screen/splash-land-mdpi.9.png`
となっています。

Monacaはクラウド上にビルド環境があるため、おそらく通常のCordovaのビルド時の画像コピーの前に、クラウドのビルド環境の`/private/tmp/monaca/<id>/project/`にリソースをコピーするという処理が入るのだと思います。
このリソースコピーでデフォルトの`portrait`は正常にコピーされるが、`landscape`として追加したリソースがコピーされず、`cp: no such file or directory:`というエラーに繋がっているのだと思います。

---

`​​.monaca-res/res‌​/android/scre‌​en/sp‌​lash-la‌​nd-mdpi.png`の指定を試してもらったのはリソースがクラウド上のそのフォルダ`/private/tmp/monaca/<id>/project/.monaca-res`にコピーされるのではないか、という推測からです。

Comment: 調査・提案ありがとうございました！先ほどMonacaサポートに問い合わせをいたしましたので、回答があり次第、こちらにてご報告いたします！

Answer (score 2):

質問者です。
Monacaサポート担当様から回答ありましたので、ご報告いたします。

**現在のMonacaの仕様では、AndroidでLandscapeを設定した場合、

スプラッシュスクリーンの画像を表示することができないようです。**

cordovaバージョンアップ以降に対応を検討中ということでした。

Comment: upvoteしました。Monacaでのスプラッシュスクリーンの制限になるのですね。[ドキュメント](https://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/cordova_5.2/splashscreen/)の内容では`「横方向 ( landscape ) ・縦方向 ( portrait ) 用の画像をそれぞれ使用できます。」`とあるのでLandscapeを利用可能に見えて紛らわしいですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます！紛らわしいですが、もしかしたら以前は別々に設定できていたかもしれませんね...。